# Making a function only available to its prototypes

Tags: javascript, function, methods, prototype

Here's what my code looks like:

```
Random = function(name) {
    this.name = name;

    this.addSomething = function(a, b) {
        return a + b;
    }
}

Random.prototype.addStuff = function(a, b, c, d) {
    return this.addSomething(a, b) + this.addSomething(b, d);
}
```

I need `this.addSomething` to only be available in the function itself and its prototypes, however this isn't working.

Could someone point me in the right direction and show me how to do this? Thanks.

Comment: I'm unclear. You want it to be a local function inside the constructor, but also available on the prototype, i.e. inherited by instances?

Comment: Yes. `this.addSomething()` should be available to the constructor and the prototypes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to make "private" members/methods is something like this:

```
Random = function(name) {
    this.name = name;

    function add_something(a, b) {
        return a + b;
    }
    this.addStuff = function(a, b, c, d) {
        return add_something(a, b) + add_something(b, d);
    }
}
```

**Edit**: as RobG mentioned in his answer, [this article](http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html) by Douglas Crockford will help you understanding how public, private and privileged members/methods work in Javascript. It's an extremely reccomended reading.

Comment: Well, the way I have my code laid out it uses prototypes. I'm trying your solution with my code by changing `this.myFunctName` to a function declaration and changing my prototypes to use `myFunctName()` but now its saying it isn't defined.

Comment: @Fike because it isn't defined in that scope. Try something like `(function(){ function addSmth(){...} /* constructor here */ /* prototype stuff here */ }())`

Comment: Sorry but that confused me a bit. Could you edit the answer and show me how to do that with the code I posted? Thanks!

Comment: @Fike Take a closer look to how `addStuff` is defined. It's an _anonymous_ function assigned to a member. Private members and methods can't be accessed by prototyped functions, you'll have to define them in the object constructor. This consumes memory, but gives the result you're looking for. Read the linked article by Dougles Crockford for further details.

Answer (score 1):

Functions called as a constructor return a plain Object by default. You can make them return some other type of object, but that object wont inherit from the constructor's prototype. Also, you can't change the `[[Prototype]]` of a function object (ignoring the deprecated [**proto**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto) property).

The only way that a constructor (which is a function) and objects created by the constructor can have the same method is for both to share an object in their `[[Prototype]]` chain. That can only be done by extending Object.prototype, since that is the only object that both a Function and an Object can share.

Also, you can't prevent access to public methods of objects. You can emulate [private members](http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html), but it's pretty weak emulation. However you can have a method check that the calling object is an instance of a particular "class", e.g.

```
function Foo(){}

Foo.prototype.bar = function() {
  return this instanceof Foo? 'success' : 'failure';
}

var foo = new Foo();
var blah = {};

// Call bar method of an instance of Foo
alert(foo.bar()); // success

// Call bar method on some other object
alert(Foo.prototype.bar.call(blah)); // failure
```

Any such solution in javascript is easily spoofed, it's impossible to do what you want in a robust way.

Comment: +1 for citing that article by Douglas Crockford. It really opened my eyes when I began with Javascript. Forgive me if I add that same link to my answers, it's just to underline its importance.